# Socket vs Database in Game Creation

Tags: android, sockets, firebase, libgdx

I am creating a multiplayer game for android which will be like: you choose a character, you get an oponnent and during this player versus player "fight", they only click in buttons which are the "attacks".

Though at first it seemed like a simple task I am not quite sure how to do the communication between the users of which attack was selected by the opponent, but I've come up with two possibilities: Sockets and Databases.

Sockets seemed like the best option, however, what I've found is that they only work on the same network, what definetly doesn't serve my purpose.

About Database I am not sure if it is a good idea, as making so many requests to check whether the other player has already chosen would make the game laggy I think. I have even created an Firebase account, as their Realtime Database seemed much more reasonable to use, but I couldn't find any way in which I could integrate Firebase with LibGDX (which I am using for this app).

To sum up, the answer is: what is the best way to exchange data quickly? How could I implement it using LibGDX?

I am using Android Studio if it helps anything and am on 0$ budget.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the $0 budget then getting a VPS (virtual private server) is out of the question. So you need another alternative. Run your server from home, from your own PC.

Your next step would be to get a free dns service which will redirect a web address to your home routers IP address and from there you can setup your router to redirect ports directly to your PC. These can be web ports, or ports for TCP use.

You will then have a choice of what to use:

1 - Web sockets which can be used by various languages that will run on the server.

2 - TCP/IP server which is less overhead than web sockets and is direct communication via TCP to your server.

Both of the above will have their strengths, but it is up to you where you start. The server software itself can be written in many languages, including Java which will be more compatible with your current Android project.

There's no way I can explain in depth any further without other questions being raised. So from here, it's a lot of research in the various technologies.

Comment: Programming a server is no problem for me but what I would really like to know is whether that is suitable for a game that relies basically on sending things to server many times in minutes. Also, in terms of speed, is it better to use database, write in files, is it better to connect through socket or requests. I referred Firebase as an alternative, because that would reduce the amount of times I would have to look for updates and believe that that would be better, just don't know how to implement the RealTime Database with LibGDX.

Comment: A TCP server would be your best bet then. One quote from this '__compute everything related to the game logic on the server__' makes perfect sense (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/249/how-to-write-a-network-game). My latency to my home server, my PC to my PC via my DNS is an average 4ms. Latency from my VPS, via my DNS, and then to my PC is 14ms. Yes it will increase, but your game dynamics will have to adjust for that.